# C# windows 7 run exe before computer shutdown

Tags: c#, .net-framework, group-policy

I want to run an executable that saves an XML file on a local drive before the computer (running on Windows 7) gets shut down.

I know it is possible to run scripts before shutdown. This can be configured in Local Group Policy Editor under Computer Configuration --> Windows Settings --> Scripts(Startup/Shutdown).

I have tried to put my executable in the shutdown property, but it does not work. How can I run an executable before the computer gets shut down? How can I hook up the shutdown event?

Comment: Have you tried to see why it didn't work at the system log?

Comment: Also have you tried it using the task scheduler too?

Comment: [I found solution for similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799955/how-to-detect-windows-shutdown-or-logoff)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Launching a process when the shutdown was initiated is a bad idea. At this stage the most likely outcome is to get back the error [1115 `ERROR_SHUTDOWN_IN_PROGRESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A much better way is to install a service and register the service to receive shutdown notifications via [`RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), see shutting down:

> Service applications receive shutdown notifications in their handler routines. To register a service control handler, use the `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` function.

A C# service would do this by setting [`CanShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canshutdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true and then handling the [`OnShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onshutdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. It is important to be service, not an application, as shutdown can occur when no session is logged on and/or multiple sessions could be running when the shutdown occurs.

Comment: This does not always work. I've set CanShutdown to true, implemented OnShutdown which writes to a simple file. The file is never written to. Service runs as local system so I know it has permissions.